# Beautiful Soup (code was working) now only returns certain tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I was scraping this website a few weeks back but some of the code no longer works.

This code returns everything as expected:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/consensus/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'hUMQK _3JPYB'})
```

However, when doing a find all on the code below it now returns an empty list and it used to work. It appears nothing has changed in the web pages HTML

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_3h0tU'})
```

[HTML image of 'div' tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9k40.png)

Comment: So what is your actual question please?

Comment: Why does the last line of code return an empty list? The tag appears to still be on the site, and it worked perfectly fine a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Hmmm yes I think that could be the problem. When I load the page you can see a delay in which items are populated. The items that still load fine populate right away and all the items that no longer work there is a visible delay when loaded. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 
I don't know if website changed how populated but works if time is allowed for page to load. Using selenium retrieves just fine. Seems likely that content is JS loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/consensus/"
d = WebDriver.Chrome()
d.get(URL)
for item in d.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3h0tU"):
    Print(item.Text)
    d.quit()
```